# How to replace \n in Impala parquet files?

Tags: regex, hadoop, hdfs, impala, parquet

I have some text data stored in parquet format in HDFS in the Hive metastore. Each observation may or may not include \n as part of the text itself.
I need to export this data to a text (tab or comma delimited) file to analyze further in Python.
If I were to run a query against the data and save to text file I would get:

id,txt
1,I like this site \n tomorrow I'll write more
2,How cool \n is this website

At that point my rows get screwed due to the extra \n.
I tried to export the data but the regexp_replace function doesn't seem to produce the stripping I was expecting:

```
select id, regexp_replace(txt,'\\n',' ') as txt
from table
limit 1000
```

Any ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: Something like this might work: `create table tableB as 
select 
    id
    regexp_replace(txt, '\\n', '') as txt
from table;`

Comment: What about `translate(txt, '\\r\\n\\f', '   ')` just to be sure you really stripped *all* kinds of EOL?

Comment: *Damn, the S.O. text formatter merged the 3 spaces into one*

Comment: I think Samson's answer is close by including other possible line-ending characters.  I would think you need to use either a character class like `[\\r\\v\\f|` or an or'd capture group `regexp_replace(text, '(\\n|\\r|\\f)', ' ') as txt` to make sure you catch everything.